# Test if the number input is not a text - RUBY

Tags: ruby

I tried to create a program that will test if the inserted input is a text or a number or special character. So I used `!a.is_a? Integer`. However my code doesn't seem to work. I got this error:

> syntax error, unexpected TCONSTANT. expecting keyword then ,

Here's my code:

```
print "Enter Number Please: "
a = gets.chomp.to_i

answer = case a

when 3
  "OUTPUT: a is 3"
when 4
 "OUTPUT: a is 4"
when !a.is_a? Integer
    "You did not enter a number."
else
  "OUTPUT: a is neither 3, nor 4"
end

puts answer
```

I understand this could be better to try with Integer(obj) but is there a way to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's several things to note here. For one, the result of `to_i` is *always* an Integer type value. Testing that `!a.is_a? Integer` is redundant as that will never fail.

You'll also need to remember that the `case` statement itself makes it very easy to compare to classes:

```
case (a)
when Integer
  puts "I'm a number!"
when String
  puts "I'm a string!"
end
```

Note that the first condition is automatically triggered for any Integer values.

There's limits on what you can put in a `when` clause even if they are fairly generous. To get the parser to properly interpret what you're asking for, you'd have to express it like this:

```
when !a.is_a?(Integer)
```

Though as noted this can be reduced down to `when Integer` so the rest of that is redundant.

You'll also want to avoid specifying something in the `case` part, and then later referring to a variable. It's confusing to anyone reading your code and probably unnecessary. If you're dealing with complicated logic, use a series of `if` statements to make things clear.

Comment: On the other hand, `gets` will always return a string, so the `when Integer` condition will never be triggered.

Comment: Also, `when !a.is_a?(Integer)` is equivalent to either `when true` or `when false` since the expressions will be expanded before they are used for comparison. They will thus never match here either. In order to check complex conditions, you have to use Procs as in `when ->(v) { !v.is_a?(Integer) }`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a ternary as well I think, like so:

```
def integer?(number)
  number.is_a?(Integer) ? "This is a number" : "This is not a number"
end
```